# DVIView and PDFView

Tags: pstricks, viewers

I have a problem, that when I use DVIview I get the correct picture but no result with PDFView.
Maybe I don't use a necessary package or the problem in the pdf program in my computer! 
here is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\scalebox{1} {%
\begin{pspicture}(0,-2.15)(4.94,2.15)
\psline[linewidth=0.04](1.92,1.63)(3.06,0.15)(4.88,1.31)(0.38,-0.73)(0.86,2.01)(4.92,1.33)(4.86,1.33)
\end{pspicture}}

%\end{center}<-- disabled by mozartstrasse!
\end{document}
```

I'm using (winshell)

I need your help :)

Comment: A bit more of a description would be helpful: are you compiling the document to `.dvi` with `latex`, then to postscript (which works), but then when you convert to `pdf` it doesn't work ?

Comment: sorry i'm not familiar with Latex, but the thing that I am using Winshell, and there are choices to compile, dvi and pdf. i need my last work to be on pdf. maybe i can save work as .dvi and then convert it to pdf .. but i dont know how!

Comment: How do you make your picture ? What kind of file is it ? What program are you using to make it (TeXmaker, Texlipse, emacs ...) ?

Comment: @ach Winshell (i added more information in my last comment)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, all PSTricks code is to be compiled to DVI then converted to PS (`dvips`) then converted to PDF (`pdf2ps`). Alternatively you can try compiling with `xelatex`.

Comment: I get the same output with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` or `xelatex`. It may be a viewer problem.

Comment: This boils down to needing to use PSTricks with pdfLaTeX, which we have a general question about. I've duped.